# Is joint PDF always less than or equals to marginal PDF?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The question here is whether the statement below is true for PDFs:

ℙ(,) ≤ ℙ()

The answer is no, due to the fact that PDFs are not probabilities. There is an intuitive answer with an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672392/are-marginal-densities-always-greater-than-the-corresponding-joint-density/672792#672792), but I came across a more theoretical answer which I can't understand. The answer given is that by using the product rule:

ℙ(,) = ℙ(|) ℙ()

It continues the proof by stating that the conditional probability is not bounded, and if x is forced to be a function of y then the conditional probability is infinite at x=f(y). The source of the answer is at [part 3(ii) here.](https://mlpr.inf.ed.ac.uk/2020/notes/w0c_background_selftest_answers.html)

How does the conditional probability becomes infinite if x is a function of y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link does not say it is the conditional probability which is infinite, but the conditional density.  Even then it is stretching a point.

A conditional probability is a probability so is between $0$ and $1$.  If $X=f(y)$ when $Y=y$ then $x$ is fixed by $y$ and you can say $\mathbb P(X=f(y) \mid Y=y)=1$ as a conditional probability.  This is clearly finite.

But your quote is trying to say this in the language of densities, and so it says the conditional density is $p(x \mid y) = \delta(x-f(y))$ using a [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which despite the name is not a proper function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. This  $\delta(w)$ might be seen as zero when $w \not =0$ but with the property $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(w)\, dw = 1$, so some people might describe $\delta(0)$ as infinite in a special way. This same special way is what leads to mention of the infinite conditional density in your quote.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of conditional PDFs but accidentally wrote it as probability instead. I may be mixing up joint and conditional PDFs but when x=f(y) does it mean something like 0 < x < y < 1? Also (−())  only occurs at certain points/sections in the PDF namely where x=f(y) right?

Comment: @phatasma-coder $x=f(y)$ just means that if you know $y$ then you know $x$ exactly; there are no particular constraints on the function or the values of $x$ and $y$.  When that is true, your link would say $p(x \mid y) = \delta(x-f(y))$ but not otherwise, while I would say $\mathbb P(X=f(y) \mid Y=y)=1$ to cause less confusion.

Comment: Do you have any material that establishes (∣)=(−())? When I cover topics related to conditional PDFs, I can only find material which relates it to joint and marginal PDFs, but not with the Dirac delta function.